# How will the name Vega be pronounced in German?

Tags: pronunciation, person-names

With an /f/ or with a /v/ (f and v like in English..)? 
And while we're at it, How does this name sound in German? Does it have any bad associations?

Comment: No bad associations

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wega   ;)

Comment: Like the v in vanilla.

Answer (score 7):

*Vega* is pronounced with a /v/, not an /f/.

The star's name in German also is rendered as *Wega* sometimes.

Comment: Not sometimes, but **W**ega is the more common German name.

Comment: @Janka the practice to Germanize these names is not universally followed. That is, *Wega* is the German name, but I found *Vega* to be much more common, despite what wikipedia says. But either might be anecdotal, or there is a change towards "V" again like in other fields.

Comment: I doubt that more than a bit because astronomy was a school subject in Eastern Germany and sure they used **W**ega. So, apart from people actually working in the field of astronomy, you can be pretty sure the majority of people in Germany still uses **W**ega.

Comment: My (also East German) astronomy teacher used *Vega*, so there might be a switch? Similar to *Wismut* and *Äther* falling out of favor compared to *Bismut* and *Ether*.